# select dropdown list item findbytext without case sensitivity vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to select one item in drop down list in ASP.NET written with VB.NET - I have values and texts in listbox like this:

```
Volvo
Audi
etc...
```

But values coming from other place in upper case... VOLVO, AUDI..

This code:

```
dropdownlist.FindByValue("CAPITAL")
```

Is not working and giving `null` for Volvo.. please help.

Comment: No native method for that.. you'll have to write your own. Tim answer is a good one for example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way would be LINQ:

```
Dim volvoItem = dropdownlist.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().
    FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.Text.Equals("Volvo", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

C#:

```
var volvoItem = dropdownlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
   .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Text.Equals("Volvo", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: simply elegant!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
foreach(ListItem li in dropdownlist.Items)
    {
        if (String.Compare(li.Text, myLabel.Text, true) == 0)
            myCustomValidator.IsValid = false;  // Match Found !
    }
```

Comment: Not efficient if you work with a lot of items. Then a search will be your better option if you need to improve on performance and memory usage. But to improve on your solution. Just exit the for loop once the item is found

Answer (score 0):

Like Tim said LINQ would be you answer.
in C# try the following:

```
var item = dropdownlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>().SingleOrDefault(li =>
                                               li.Text.ToUpper() == "VOLVO");
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional variants, using framework CI comparison.  VB:

```
uiList.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)
  .FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.Text.Equals(comparand, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

C#:

```
uiList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
  .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Text.Equals(comparand, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

You could also use `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` depending on your requirements.  These are generally safer than comparing with `ToUpper/ToLower`, because some cultures have unexpected casing rules.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was asked and while there seems to be solutions, those solutions don't appear to apply to a web page. So I created one that will work on a web site. I created a Static Class called Extensions (C#) and put the following code into the Class:

```
public static ListItem FindByText(this ListItemCollection collection, string text, bool ignoreCase) {
    ListItem tmp = new ListItem();
    if(collection != null)
        foreach(ListItem li in collection) {
            if(li.ToString().ToLower() == text.ToLower()) {
                return li;
            }
        }
    return tmp;
}
```

In the code where I needed this I called it like this:

```
ddlStates.SelectedIndex = ddlStates.Items.IndexOf(ddlStates.Items.FindByText(User.State, true));
```

If you leave off the second parameter then the default FindByText function is called which is case sensitive. ddlStates is a dropdown of all 50 states and the User.State is where the user is from. I needed to get the Index of the state, which required a ListIndex value and not just text, so it would put that into the dropdown when I called up the Users account. But, the states are in various conditions of Upper and Lower case. If for any reason there is no match, it just leaves it at the first selection in the dropdown which is a blank selection. This leaves it up to the User to select the appropriate State.

I hope this works for someone who thinks this option should have been there all along.