# How to add a new value to Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I am loading datasource to Dropdown list and binding, but in some scenario new value is coming (case sensitive) so i cannot able to set as selected value for the drop downlist?
How to acheive this, means to show the datagrid selected value as text in drop down list?

Populating data into dropdown list

```
Me.RmtRouterName.DataSource = Me.datareader_1param("pr_list_dev_by_site", 
    SiteID, "@enter_value")
Me.RmtRouterName.DataTextField = "devname"
Me.RmtRouterName.DataValueField = "devname"
```

Reading value from datagrid

```
tmpstr = MyIIF(Me.SiteInfo1.Tables(SiteInfoTableName).Rows(0), "RmtRouterName")
If (tmpstr = String.Empty) Then
   Me.RmtRouterName.SelectedIndex = -1
Else
   Me.RmtRouterName.SelectedValue = tmpstr
```

in some cases the datareader values and datgrid values are mismatching (due to case sensitive) how to overcome this problem

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9195606/961695

Answer (score 0):

In your `Else` logic, attempt to find the text value in the drop down list before attempting to set the `SelectedValue`, like this:

Helper Function:

```
Public Function FindByTextCaseInsensitive(ByVal ctl As ListControl, ByVal text As String) As ListItem
    If ctl Is Nothing Then 
        Return Nothing
    End If

    For Each li As ListItem In ctl.Items
        If String.Compare(li.Text, text, True) = 0 Then 
            Return li
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Now in your `Else` block, do this:

```
Else
    Dim foundItem As ListItem = FindByTextCaseInsensitive(tmpstr)

    If foundItem Is Nothing Then
        Me.RmtRouterName.SelectedIndex = -1
    Else
        Me.RmtRouterName.SelectedValue = tmpstr
    End If
End If
```